# How to echo get_post_meta (Fluent-Framework)

Tags: post-meta

PHP beginner here.

I purchased the Fluent-Framework plugin, which allows me to easily crease Post Types, Meta Boxes, and Option Pages within my theme. I am having trouble echoing the Meta Boxes, however.

[Here are the official documents.](http://support.nohalfpixels.com/documentation/fluent-framework/)
My Post Type Name: `front_page`

My HTML:

```
<button> <pre><?php print_r ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'test', true) ); ?></pre> </button>
```

The HTML Output:

```
<button> 
    <pre>Array ( [text] => This Is A Test ) </pre> 
</button>
```

My Meta (Fluent-Framework):

```
// $meta
$meta = array();

// $meta $args
$meta['text'] = array(
    'dash_icon' => 'list-view',
    'title' =>  __('Section Options', 'fluent'),
    'description' => __('This allows you to change the general settings for your new Section.','fluent'),
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'caps' => array(),
    'fields' => array(
        'text' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'title' => __('Section Style', 'fluent'),
            'sub_title' => __('Set to small, white, grey, dark, darker, black, or parallax one-four.', 'fluent'),
            'required' => true,
            'description' => __('This is just a text field.', 'fluent'),
            'default' => 'dark',
            'option_name' => 'test',
            'seperate' => true
        ),
    ),
);
```

I need it to return the value of the meta input. Can anyone help me? I'm really lost.

EDIT: Sorry for the 3rd party plugin question... just found out that kind of thing isn't allowed here. :)

Thanks!

Comment: do this. `<button><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'test', true); ?></button>`

Comment: This echoes "Array" as a string. Close - at least I'm echoing something! Mind helping me further? :)

Comment: Try this also. `<button><?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'test', true); ?></button>`. Where are you using it? Inside or outside the loop. If it returns a array then your post meta contains array.

Comment: Returns blank, unfortunately. It is running inside of my loop.

Comment: Okay, it's an array. use this and add output in your question. `<pre><?php print_r ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'test', true) ); ?></pre>`

Comment: Done and updated, as requested. Returns my value, but its nested in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay as you added output of array.
You can use the following to get the result. This will print the value of `test` meta key.

```
<button><?php $my_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'test', true ); echo $my_meta["test"]; ?></button>
```

if your meta key is `custom-name` then you can get it like this.

```
<?php $my_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom-name', true ); echo $my_meta["custom-name"]; ?>
```

Comment: Nope, returns blank. :( I linked the guide but I cannot make sense of it to output what I need. I am following along though, I understand it so far.

Comment: I updated my answer, please use this `echo $my_meta[test];`

Comment: No echo. I'm trying things and experimenting as you're helping me, but no dice. I really appreciate you helping me, I think we're really close so far. The developer hasn't written me all day, so I'm stuck until we can figure this out.

Comment: Although it should work but try adding double quote. `<button><?php $my_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'test', true ); echo $my_meta["test"]; ?></button>`.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you!!!! It worked. Selected as answer good sir!

Comment: Great! I am glad I could help. About your query on downvote, probably because this question is for commercial 3rd party plugin and/or theme. Which is off-topic here. :) anyway happy learning.

Comment: Oh... I had no idea that was not allowed. Whoops! Well, thank you anyway for taking the time. It truly is appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Do you mind helping me one more time with a `radio`? Trying to get it to say `if ($meta_option[divider] == "yes") { ?> <div class="divider"></div> <? } else { }; ?>`